# This language is not context free but has a PDA?

Tags: automata, computational-mathematics, pushdown-automata

Language is
$B = \{w \in \Sigma^*  \mid w = a^n\#b^{2n}\#a^n \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Assume the alphabet is $\Sigma = \{a, b, \#\}$.

I know this language is not context-free.

**But** below is a PDA that accepts all words from the above language:
[image: see PDA here]

**But isn't this a contradiction? How can the language not be context free and still be recognized by a PDA?**

Comment: I think you would accept something like $a^n\#b^{n+m}\#a^m$

Comment: Right, so wouldn't it still be a contradiction though (under the theorem that a language is context-free iff it is recognized by a PDA) because eventhough lang B is a special case of the language accepted by the given PDA where n=m, it still accepts all words in B. 
So technically, B *should* be context-free?

Also, B can be proven not context-free by pumping lemma.

Comment: @bhujangee Your "special case" argument does not make sense; just because $B$ is a subset of a context-free language, it does not need to be context-free. In fact, *every* language is a subset of $\Sigma^*$ but of course that doesn't make every language context-free!

Comment: @hgmath thanks. That clears it up!